# Two way bridge between native android and progressive web apps in trusted web application

Tags: javascript, android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, twa

As per current understanding from TWA [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity), we can pass message between native android and web using URL intents and query parameters/custom headers.

I want to pass information from web to native and return response based on the action to that message in native to web on the same page. I can do this by reopening another trusted web activity. But this leads to page load and destroys the existing state of the page.

In other words, I am trying to replicate a request-response type of behaviour in TWA without page transition on web.

Sample use case : From PWA, I want to call android native code to print a string. In case of failure cases, I want to send back the error response to PWA.

Is there a way this can be done without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1):

Trusted Web Activities don't have a runtime communication bridge between Android and the web app, so the short answer to the question is that this cannot be done without reloading the page.

There's a long discussion thread here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/issues/55. Please, do chime in and describe your use case.